# How to write a Generic Trait in Rust, which itself is dependent based on another generic Trait

Tags: generics, rust

I am writing this code, where I have a generic-trait which is dependent on another generic-trait to enforce some property.

I have this trait `FactoryGen` which is dependent on type `M`, in which I want to enforce trait type of `CommonKeyObj`, that itself is having 2 generic trait on type `F` and `T`.

Here is my code:
[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5a0ccf034dae7097dc041c447422cad6)

```
// some traits
pub trait CommonKeyObj<P, T> {
    fn new(key: P,
           data: Option<T>) -> Self;
    fn clone(&self) -> Self;
    fn get_property(&self) -> Option<T>; // whoever implements this traits should be able to "get_property" (,"clone" and "new")
}

// followed struct implements above trait
pub struct GenericKeyObj<P, T> {
    key: P,
    data: Option<T>
}

impl<P: Clone, T: Clone> CommonKeyObj<P, T> for GenericKeyObj<P, T> {
    fn new(key: P, data: Option<T>) -> Self {
        GenericKeyObj::<P, T> {
            key, data,
        }
    }
    
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        GenericKeyObj::<P, T> {
            key: self.key.clone(), 
            data: Some(self.data.unwrap().clone()),
        }
    }
    
    fn get_property(&self) -> Option<T> { // this is one iteration of get_property -- specific to "GenericKeyObj"
        self.data
    }
}

// more traits

pub trait FactoryGen<M> { // Question: here the type that I want to enforce is of trait type: CommonKeyObj and the method is "get_property" (optionally "clone" and "new")
    fn new(val: &M) -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized;
    fn access(&self, obj: M) -> u64;
}

pub struct ObjA {
    access_type: u64,
    resource: String,
}

impl<M: CommonKeyObj<P, T>> FactoryGen<M> for ObjA {
    fn new(val: &M) -> Self {
        ObjA {
            access_type: 0,
            resource: String::from("ObjA"),
        }
    }
    
    fn access(&self, val: M) -> u64 {
        val.get_property(self.resource) // I want to make sure that I can (enforce to) "get_property" from whatever type is passed here
    }
}

pub struct ObjB {
    access_type: u64,
    resource: String,
}

impl<M: CommonKeyObj<P, T>> FactoryGen<M> for ObjB {
    fn new(val: &M) -> Self {
        ObjB {
            access_type: 2,
            resource: String::from("ObjB"),
        }
    }
    
    fn access(&self, val: M) -> u64 {
        val.get_property(self.resource)  // I want to make sure that I can (enforce to) "get_property" from whatever type is passed here
    }
}

// now we are going to use them
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct DummyObj {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
    city: String, 
    zip: u64,
}

impl DummyObj {
    fn new(name: String, age: u8, city: String, zip: u64) -> Self {
        DummyObj {
            name,
            age,
            city,
            zip,
        }
    }
}

pub fn some_factory_method<T>(s: &str, val: &T) -> Box<dyn FactoryGen<T>> {
    if s == "objectA" {
        Box::new(ObjA::new(val))
    }
    else {
        Box::new(ObjB::new(val))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = DummyObj::new(String::from("Peter"), 64, String::from("San Hose"), 79097);
    let key = String::from("address");
    let obj = GenericKeyObj::new(key, Some(data));
    
    let obj_manager_a = some_factory_method::<GenericKeyObj<P, T>>("objectA", &obj);
    println!("{}", obj_manager_a.access());
    
    let obj_manager_b = some_factory_method::<GenericKeyObj<P, T>>("objectB", &obj);
    println!("{}", obj_manager_b.access());
}
```

I am not sure if this is something possible in Rust. Can someone help me with that please? Also if this is not possible, what could be  a close alternative re-implementation of this?

PS:

There could be other compilation problem in the code, but I am only forced on the core trait problem stated above.

New in Rust.

Comment: There are a lot of errors in your code unrelated to the question you're asking. Can you fix those first?

Comment: @cdhowie sorry about that. I have updated now!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve this unconstrained type parameter error in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129214/how-to-solve-this-unconstrained-type-parameter-error-in-rust) (The most obvious approach, doing `impl<P, T, M: CommonKeyObj<P, T>> FactoryGen<M> for ObjA` fails with the above error.)

Comment: @cdhowie I did see the link that you have shared, but there are some key difference between what I am doing here vs what has been posted in the link I am trying to inherit on a generic trait, from another generic trait.  I am still investigating the solution, but as of now I am not seeing how it is solving my problem.

Comment: The errant code in that question (`impl<M: Message, MH: MessageHandler<M>> MessageSystem<MH>`) pretty much exactly matches what you're trying to do, except that you're implementing a trait instead of implementing on the type directly. The solution, IIRC, is the same.